# How to style only single word of a WordPress post title

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am wondering whether i could style only a single word from a post title in wordpress, like adding span in between. But Wordpress renders title as a whole and cannot find how to do this.

For eg: The title can be like "Hello, welcome to this world"
And here I would like to style a single word like "welcome" only differently.

My HTML template for title is like

```
<h2>Hello, <span>welcome</span> to this world</h2>
```

but in wordpress we could retrieve the title entirely only, using

```
the_title();
```

tag. and the output will be like

```
<h2>Hello, welcome to this world</h2>
```

How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the pattern? There has to be a pattern, if you want this automated.

Answer (score 1):

One approach, using native JavaScript:

```js
function h1Words() {
  // finding the first/only <h1> element:
  var h1 = document.querySelector('h1'),
    // working out whether we can use textContent or innerText to access the text:
    textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
    // a simple counter:
    wordNum = 1;

    // setting the innerHTML of the <h1> element
       // accessing the text of the <h1>,
       // splitting that text on word-boundary characters (/\b/) with
       // split() using a regular expression,
       // iterating over the resuls using map(), 'chars' is the array-element:
       // if the 'chars' variable is a string of alpha-numerics (/^w+$/)
       // we wrap that sequence in a <span> element (with classes),
       // otherwise we return the 'chars' unchanged:
    h1.innerHTML = h1[textProp].split(/\b/).map(function(chars) {
      return (/^\w+$/).test(chars) ? '<span class="word word' + wordNum+++'">' + chars + '</span>' : chars;
    // joining the array-elements back together to re-form a string:
    }).join('');
}

h1Words();
```

```css
h1 .word {
  color: rgba(200,200,200,0.6);
}

h1 .word3 {
  color: orange;
}

h1 .word:nth-child(1) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello, welcome to this world</h1>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Conditional ('ternary') operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).
- [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: +1 for a creative answer to a poorly explained question.

Answer (score -1):

With css we can do this.

```
    h2 > span{color:red;}
```